# How to Call Matlab GUI From C# Window Form Application

Tags: c#, matlab

I have written the Iris Recognition Application in mat-lab and written another application in C#.

Now how can I integrate them together? I want the iris to be recognized in the C# Examination Application.

So i want to know how to i call Mat-lab login GUI from a C# Button. When the Visual Studio Project will complied the first Gui will be login form Which i build in mat-lab and Similarly when Recognition is Completed  the Exam Application will Appear .

Problem 1: Tell me How I can Call the Mat-lab GUI From C# form

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has the Compiler SDK toolbox (for version R2015a, for earlier versions it was called Builder NE) that you can use to package your MATLAB code into a .NET assembly that can be called from C#.

MATLAB Figures and GUIs are supported with this feature, except for built-in Apps (e.g., imaqtool).

Comment: thanks for your Reply kindly tell me in detail if some template is available or Tutorial kindly write some step i am new to Mat-lab

Comment: Hey Shery, the toolbox is pretty involved as there are lots of details like data marshaling and environment setup to consider, so I can't give instructions in an answers post here.  I recommend learning about the product from the MathWorks site and reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In matlab first you create the standalone exe using the matlab coder tool. then start the exe from c# by below code.

```
Process.Start("path\example.exe");
```

Note: confirm that in your system have MCR.
      For creating standalone exe refer following links
[Link1](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/11/18/deploying-standalone-applications/), [link2](http://in.mathworks.com/videos/matlab-compiler-overview-92528.html)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be use dllimport to call matlab generated c library, and if there is a gui in between, then matlab gui would show up, make sure import/start mcr first.